# LINQ GroupBy a name, but how to get Id of users?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, group-by, datagridview

I want to display how many transfers did every customer.
I want to display `CustomerId`, `Name` and `Totaly` amount of transfers.
I mean I want to display `CustomerId` too, not only `Name` and `Amount` transfers.

Everything works fine except `CustomerId`: it is empty in my DataGridview.
I don't know how to do and I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Here is my code:

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
   var statistic = (from u in db.Transfers
                    join c in db.Customers on u.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
                    where u.IsActive == true && u.Paid == true
                    group u by c.FirstName  into g
                    select new
                    {
                      // here I get Headertext but not Id's value
                      Id = g.Select(x =>x.CustomerId),
                      Name = g.Key,
                      Totaly = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Totaly).ToList();
                    
                    if (statistic != null)
                    {
                        dgvCustomerList.DataSource = statistic;
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to group it by `CustomerId` (because `CustomerId` is unique, you will get distinct customers inside select and then you can use `FirstOrDefault()` for getting FirstName property):

```
    using (Db db = new Db())
{
   var statistic = (from u in db.Transfers
                    join c in db.Customers on u.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
                    where u.IsActive == true && u.Paid == true
                    group u by c.CustomerId  into g
                    select new
                    {
                      Id = g.Key, // here I get Headertext but not Id's value
                      Name = g.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,
                      Totaly = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Totaly).ToList();
                    
                    if (statistic != null)
                    {
                        dgvCustomerList.DataSource = statistic;
                    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I got already to work with litle modification from Arsalan. Even your code works fine. Thank you both of you guys.

Comment: grouping it by multiple properties is not optimal. a better way to do is to group by indexer property in this case CustomerId

Comment: in indexer property, I mean database index. the generated query will be faster and optimal

Answer (score 1):

You can group by both `customerId` and `FirstName`

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
   var statistic = (from u in db.Transfers
                    join c in db.Customers on u.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
                    where u.IsActive == true && u.Paid == true
                    group u by new {key c.FirstName,key c.CustumerId}  into g
                    select new
                    {
                      Id = g.Key.CustumerId,//g.Select(x =>x.CustomerId), // here I get Headertext but not Id's value
                      Name = g.Key.FirstName,
                      Totaly = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Totaly).ToList();
                    
                    if (statistic != null)
                    {
                        dgvCustomerList.DataSource = statistic;
                    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes it's working now with litle modificastion of your code.